# How to make a list of ApplicationUser type that could be iterated over?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a list or IEnumerable (any iterable list) of ApplicationUser type as a prop. I want to make this list of of ApplicationUser type so that i can iterate over it in a view. How can this be done?

```
public class FollowingsViewModel
{
    public List <ApplicationUser> { get; set; }
}
```

That's what I am trying to do.. but this gives a syntax error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1519 Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration GigHub F:\raza\3rd_Year\DataBase\Web\GigHub\GigHub\ViewModels\FollowingsViewModel.cs 11 Active

Comment: and 9 others almost similar

Comment: you need just give name your list

Comment: Ohh.  yeah!! silly me.. sorry to bother you guys.. thanks though

Comment: no problem, you can mark as resolve(armin)

Answer (score 1):

```
public List <ApplicationUser> applicationUsers { get; set; }
```